# How to fix "cannot find symbol error" for my program?

Tags: java, parsing, find, symbols

I am struggling to find why I keep receiving this message:

```
Integer.java:13: error: cannot find symbol
         num = Integer.parseInt(numStr);
                      ^
  symbol:   method parseInt(String)
  location: class Integer
Integer.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
         num2 = String.parseInt(numStr2);
                      ^
  symbol:   method parseInt(String)
  location: class String
2 errors
```

Is there something I missed? Thanks.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Integer
{
   public static void main (String[] args)
   {
      String numStr, numStr2, sum, product;
      int num, num2, again;

      do
      {
         numStr = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter an integer: ");
         num = Integer.parseInt(numStr);

         numStr2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter another integer: ");
         num2 = Integer.parseInt(numStr2);

         sum = "The sum is " + ((num + num2));
         product = " and  the product is " + ((num * num2));

         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, sum);
         again = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Do Another?");
      }

      while (again == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION);
  }
}
```

Comment: Rename your class name. Java already has class named `Integer`

Comment: @Jonjongot - nope. `int` is a keyword, `Integer` is not. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/_keywords.html

Comment: If you have your **own** `Integer` class than **you** need to define its methods.

Comment: @PM77-1 Still a terrible idea regardless.

Comment: @August - terrible it is

Comment: Java.lang.• package is always imported implicitly so there is name collision

Comment: @Jonjongot Thanks! :D I renamed my class to something else and it works now.

Comment: add the full path name. java.lang.Integer.parseInt(numStr);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should rename your class to another name, perhaps call it "IntegerMachine" and not "Integer". Java already has a native class with the name "Integer", and by naming your own class the same would mean that instead of calling java.lang.Integer.parseInt(string), which you intended, you are calling .Integer.parseInt(), for which the latter does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

@Ricardo Desu Perez

change your below line

```
num = Integer.parseInt(numStr);
```

to following

```
num = java.lang.Integer.parseInt(numStr);
```

if you intend to call default parseInt method in Integer class 
else
write your own version of parseInt(String) method